# Splitting the String with arithmetic operators and functions in java

Tags: java, regex, split

I need some guidance on how to split a string with arithmetic operators and functions in java
for the example String is:

```
"string1"+"String2" >= 10 * function1() / function2()
```

operators may be:

```
+ - * / ** / % / ( ) = != > < <= >=
```

After Split 
I need the output like:

```
array[0]=string1
array[1]=string2
array[2]=10
```

I need only things inside the double quotes and contants or numbers, not a functions(function1()) or operators.

I need regular expression for this problem

Comment: While it's probably possible to do this with a regex -- why do you not look at something like JLex to build a lexer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a regex for extracting things inside the double quotes and numbers, then you can use this java code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"(\\w+)\"|\\b\\d+\\b");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(
        "\"string1\"+\"String2\" >= 10 * function1() / function2()");
    List<String> parts = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (m.find()) {
        if (m.group(1) != null)
            parts.add(m.group(1));
        else
            parts.add(m.group(0));
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts.toArray(new String[] {})));        
}
```

which outputs:

```
[string1, String2, 10]
```

Note: I'm not sure that regex is the best tool in this case. As others suggested you may want to investigate the use of a parser.

Comment: Thanks for your code, I need output like string1,string2,10 without double quotes . Can you can for this ?

Comment: @user782482: I've modified my code to address your request. I hope this helps.

Comment: yes,It's working fine.One more help, If i want functions also in that array means what should i do? like [string1,string2,10,function1(),function2()]

Comment: If you want to have `functionX()` in the output then change the regex as follows: `\"(\\w+)\"|\\b\\d+\\b|function\\d+\\(\\)`

Answer (score 3):

You can remove all operators from string and then match everything except strings with `()` in the end.

Comment: When removing the operators use a special char and then split the string using the special char.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to create a parser, e.g. using JavaCC or maybe parboiled
https://github.com/sirthias/parboiled/wiki/ (haven't tried that one yet)

Comment: I like the idea of JavaCC though it might be too heavy since there's no grammar involved so just a lexer migh suffice. +1 nevertheless ;)